# Breadcrumbs error in Kohana

Tags: kohana, helper, breadcrumbs

I am implementing breadcrumbs on my application using Kohana framework using https://github.com/RaymondCrandall/kohana-breadcrumbs

I have a Category section which internally has many other sub categories n so on. One controller called Category.php having two action:
1. index($cat) (called when I click on each category until it reaches the last sub category)
2. category($cat) (called when I click on last sub category i.e. on leaf node )

The way I wrote my code into both action is:

```
        Breadcrumbs::add(Breadcrumb::factory()->set_title("Home")->set_url(url::site()));
        Breadcrumbs::add(Breadcrumb::factory()->set_title("Categories")->set_url(url::site('categories')));

        if($cat != NUll) {
            Breadcrumbs::add(Breadcrumb::factory()->set_title($cat)->set_url(url::site('categories/' .$cat )));
        }
        $actual = Breadcrumbs::get();
        $view->breadcrumbs = $actual;
```

The problem is it shows me only three levels. How can I extend it to 4th level or more.
Eg. home>category>stationary>dress. How can I save my previous values of $actual?

So when I click on dress, index action is called and replaces my array with
 home>category>dress since parameter '$cat= dress'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is much related to the mentioned plugin.

You are just using the category name string, a simple string doesn't even know what is a category, event less what is it's name, and hierarchy.

I see three options:

1. Get all your parent relations from the DB, or wherever you store them, run a loop that prints breadcrumbs, until it reaches the leaf.
2. Map your actions so they accept full path, for example "index/stationary/dress", and extract all the values from the path parameters (no need for DB call in  this case)
3. Store an array with previous values in session, and recreate breadcrumb from that array. Also no DB calls here. Note that, in this case you have to be careful when to empty the array. Depends on your logic. You would have to recognize when a leaf has been hit, and empty the array then.